# Typescript How to express if present should not be undefined

Tags: typescript

How to express the below in typescript?

```
type LanguageName = "javascript" | "typescript" | "java" | "csharp"

type LanguageToWasmMap = {
  [key in LanguageName]: Exclude<LanguageName, key>
}

//I want the below to not throw error
const languageNameToWasmNameMap: LanguageToWasmMap = {
  "javascript" : "typescript"
}

//I want the below to throw error
const languageNameToWasmNameMapWithUndefined: LanguageToWasmMap = {
  "javascript" : undefined
}
```

Typescript playground : [Click Here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/AQ4FwTwBwU2AZAhgOwOYFdGpgOUQWzgF5gAiAK0QDdEBnAYwCcBLKMU4AHzMlgZbYduFaoiFl6tABaJGUUgChQwJaF5wkaTNgAqAewDqdfAFlEUYCQDeq5QG0A1jAjBmyBCgxZcBGAF0ALmAAUQAPegAbdAATGAAeTS9sPEIAGmAnCAA%20W2AAX1zcgHoigElgAHcUMHApOAAjGAi9CvA9YGQ9GrApRhbgGEY%20xlz6PWRaGojPbR9CfSNafBSYMyggxNmF4zXLYBtlEBEaflZ2YCDSdVPBXILlYrLK6tqGpv6wdp6%201sHh0fGk2A0y03hW2yWKzWBmYPQAqshYgAzNwwaIbGbeCGmcx7A6HY50JhnDhBdCImAo5Bou7AIA)

On thinking further, it makes sense to make the LanguageToWasmMap to be Optional as that it what it implies and do a runtime check for undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Partial` to tell TS that all the keys are not required.

```
    type LanguageName = "javascript" | "typescript" | "java" | "csharp"
    
    type LanguageToWasmMap = {
      [key in LanguageName]: Exclude<LanguageName, key>
    }
    
    //I want the below to not throw error
    const languageNameToWasmNameMap: Partial<LanguageToWasmMap> = {
      "javascript" : "typescript"
    }
    
    //I want the below to throw error
    const languageNameToWasmNameMapWithUndefined: LanguageToWasmMap = {
      "javascript" : undefined
    }
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/AQ4FwTwBwU2AZAhgOwOYFdGpgOUQWzgF5gAiAK0QDdEBnAYwCcBLKMU4AHzMlgZbYduFaoiFl6tABaJGUUgChQwJaF5wkaTNgAqAewDqdfAFlEUYCQDeq5QG0A1jAjBmyBCgxZcBGAF0ALmAAUQAPegAbdAATGAAeTS9sPEIAGmAnCAA+W2AAX1zcgHoigElgAHcUMHApOAAjGAi9CvA9YGQ9GrApRhbgGEY+xlz6PWRaGojPbR9CfSNafBSYMygggAVZMGZECISZ7wXjNazLYBtlEBEaflZ2YCDSdTvBXILlYrLK6tqGpv6YHaPT6rUGw1G40mwGmWm8K2OSxWawMzB6AFVkLEAGZuGDRIKJWaI0zmc6XK43OhMe4cILoLEwXHIfHvYBAA)

Comment: if I am using partial, then it will allow `undefined` for values

Comment: it doesn't. did you check the playground I linked?

Comment: Please check https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/AQ4FwTwBwU2AZAhgOwOYFdGpgOUQWzgF5gAiAK0QDdEBnAYwCcBLKMU4AHzMlgZbYduFaoiFl6tABaJGUUgChQwJaF5wkaTNgAqAewDqdfAFlEUYCQDeq5QG0A1jAjBmyBCgxZcBGAF0ALmAAUQAPegAbdAATGAAeTS9sPEIAGmAnCAA+W2AAX1zcgHoigElgAHcUMHApOAAjGAi9CvA9YGQ9GrApRhbgGEY+xlz6PWRaGojPbR9CfSNafBSYMygggAVZMGZECISZ7wXjNazLYBtlEBEaflZ2YCDSdTvBVNzryRk5UiD0ZFiADM3DBorkCspimVKtVag0mv0wO0en1WoNhqNxpNgNMtN4Vsclis1gZmD0AKoAmDA5CgoKJWaE0zmc6XK43OhMe4cP5Ummg8HAIA

Comment: you can see the error `undefined is not assignable to ...`? Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: Please look at line #10 in the link above. I want that to error

Comment: I believe this is the right way to express the type and added runtime check for undefined. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to make it optional, and set `exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true` in tsconfig to disallow `underfined`s for optional

```
type LanguageName = "javascript" | "typescript" | "java" | "csharp"

type LanguageToWasmMap = {
  [key in LanguageName]?: Exclude<LanguageName, key> | never
}

//I want the below to not throw error
const languageNameToWasmNameMap: LanguageToWasmMap = {
  "javascript": "typescript"
}

//I want the below to throw error
const languageNameToWasmNameMapWithUndefined: LanguageToWasmMap = {
  "javascript": undefined
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAMghgOwOYFc5IgOTgW2gXigCIArOANzgGcBjAJwEsxgioAfY0SWx51j0hTj9iNKgAs4dMEQBQsrtHjI0GACoB7AOrUcAWThgohAN6yoUANoBrCCCgMEsRKnRZcEALoB%20AFxQAUQAPGgAbFAATCAAeZVcMbDwAGihbEAA%20digECHIIOlkAX3kAehKASSgAd0RgKGBxaAAjCFCNKvqNbI06hrp2qHz%20gpoNBCo60JdVdzxNHSocRIgDMH84mfndVeMoMwtBSh4mFn8iRWO%20ItKK6tr6xqgWto7gLr6BoY0RsYmoKZUbmWW0Wy1WWgYDQAqggogAzRwQCLraZuEH6Qy7fbEMhHegnIj%20FCwiAInIRIpQIA)

Comment: Any way to do this without changing it at project level?

Answer (score 0):

Using `as` seems to solve the issue. Not sure if this has any unintended side effects.

```
type LanguageName = "javascript" | "typescript" | "java" | "csharp"

type LanguageToWasmMap = {
  [key in LanguageName]: Exclude<LanguageName, key>
}

//I want the below to not throw error
const languageNameToWasmNameMap = {
  "javascript" : "typescript"
} as LanguageToWasmMap

//I want the below to throw error
const languageNameToWasmNameMapWithUndefined = {
  "javascript" : undefined
} as LanguageToWasmMap
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/AQ4FwTwBwU2AZAhgOwOYFdGpgOUQWzgF5gAiAK0QDdEBnAYwCcBLKMU4AHzMlgZbYduFaoiFl6tABaJGUUgChQwJaF5wkaTNgAqAewDqdfAFlEUYCQDeq5QG0A1jAjBmyBCgxZcBGAF0ALmAAUQAPegAbdAATGAAeTS9sPEIAGmAnCAA%20W2AAX1zcgHoigElgAHcUMHApOAAjGAi9CvA9YGQ9GrApRhbgGEY%20xlz6PWRaGojPbR9CfSNafBSYMwtrXJARGn5WdmAg0nVdwVy84DoPLW8F4zXC5RLyquRuuuBG5tawdp6%201sGw1G40mwGm12SvluSxWawMzB6AFVkLEAGZuGDRSzAGzKLaUHZMPYcILoFEwdHITFnC60K5JGDQ0zmIA)

Comment: "Not sure if this has any unintended side effects." It does, you give it a wrong type. Typescript now thinks `languageNameToWasmNameMap.csharp` is defined

Comment: Any way to address it?

Comment: I'm not sure, I gave you an ugly answer below. Another option would be to use a helper function for that, but that's not much prettier.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could make the the type generic, but you will need to specify the key twice:

```
    type LanguageName = "javascript" | "typescript" | "java" | "csharp"
    
    type LanguageToWasmMap<K extends LanguageName = LanguageName> = {
      [key in K]: Exclude<LanguageName, key>
    }
    
    //I want the below to not throw error
    const languageNameToWasmNameMap: LanguageToWasmMap<"javascript"> = {
      "javascript" : "typescript"
    }
    
    //I want the below to throw error
    const languageNameToWasmNameMapWithUndefined: LanguageToWasmMap = {
      "javascript" : undefined
    }
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=15&ssc=7&pln=1&pc=1#code/AQ4FwTwBwU2AZAhgOwOYFdGpgOUQWzgF5gAiAK0QDdEBnAYwCcBLKMU4AHzMlgZbYduFaoiFl6tABaJGUUgChQwJaF5wkaTNgAqAewDqdfAFlEUADwBpYDAAeYGMgAmtBCgxZcBYu61e8QgA+YBIAb1VlAG0AaxgIYGZkYCsAXQAuYABRO3oAG3RnGAtNT2xAmAAaYDiIIMjgAF8GhoB6VoBJYAB3FDBwKTgAIxg8vW7wPWBkPX6wKUZx20ZFxgb6PWRafryPbW9CfSNafAqzKEzS-aPjc4sRGn5WdhDwhpAHuiZnjkzSdSeggazWUbU6PT6A2GoyWYCm80WExgKz0a2UGy2Oz2AR8NxOZ3MBmY8wAqi4YAAzJIwZyXbG6Qy3cyhYARZQfSiPb6CYCZdDkqnIGnA4BAA)

Comment: Play link seems to be broken. As the map can extend, I don't want to add "javascript" to the types

Comment: Fixed the link.